# Copiar arquivos de backup do Gitlab para um disco externo configurando o crontab

Tags: linux, gitlab

Configurei o servidor para correr um cronjob e executar o script que faz o backup do Gitlab.

O Gitlab por sua vez gera os ficheiros `.tar` na pasta `var/opt/gitlab/backups`

O primeiro problema é que para ter acesso a pasta referida acima, tenho que aceder utilizando o `sudo -i`.

O segundo é que preciso configurar o crontab para sincronizar os arquivos da pasta `var/opt/gitlab/backups` para o disco externo `/media/<user>/usbbackup/`.

Como configurar o crontab para executar a ação descrita acima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar `&& rsync -a /var/opt/gitlab/backups/ /media/<user>/usbbackup` ao comando de backup no crontab. Dessa forma, quando o backup terminar, a cópia será feita. Tenha certeza de que o usuário que está executando o comando no crontab tenha permissão de leitura e escrita no diretório.

Você pode també gerar o backup diretamente no diretório desejado adicionando a opção `gitlab_rails['backup_path'] = '/media/<user>/usbbackup/'` ao arquivo de configuração do gitlab `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`. Lembre-se de executar `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` após a alteração.

Comment: Eu tentei isso mas da erro dizendo que não tem permissão de escrita no diretório. O que eu quero mesmo é uma cópia dos arquivos .tar e não mudar o diretório. Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode então adicionar `&& rsync -a /var/opt/gitlab/backups/ /media/<user>/usbbackup` ao comando no crontab. Dessa forma, quando o backup terminar a cópia será feita.

Comment: Mas para utilizar o `rsync` não preciso de utilizar o `sudo`?

Comment: Você não precisa de sudo. Precisa somente de permissão de escrita e leitura nos diretórios com o usuário que está executando os comandos.

Comment: Executei o `sudo -i` para mudar para a conta root e só assim consigo executar o rsync manualmente. A questão é: o crontab é executado como root?

Comment: Por padrão sim. Mas é possível alterar o usuário e até garantir que seja executado como root dessa forma: `0 0 * * * root rsync -a /var/opt/gitlab/backups/ /media/<user>/usbbackup`. Caso deseje trocar o usuário substitua o `root` pelo usuário desejado.